# How to make Intellij Idea to recognize unused properties annotated by @Value?

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

I have troubles with code inspections in IntelliJ Idea. Whenever I annotate a class property by `@Value` annotation, Idea does not mark it as unused, even if it is. In the Inspection settings I checked which annotations should cause that property is ignored, but there is nothing configure. How can I make Intellij Idea to recognize unused properties annotated by `@Value`?

IDEA Version is Commercial 15.0.4.

Here is an example of what I mean. Why is `foo` not highlighted?

[image]

Comment: Which IntelliJ version? And which edition (community or commercial?).

Comment: You have enabled Spring and Spring Boot as plugins? Also what do you want to be highlighted? The fact that the property that the annotation is on isn't used or the fact that you have a property in a file that isn't used?

Comment: I don't know what Spring and Spring Boot plugin do, I will check it. There is Spring Facet enabled in the project. What I mean should be described by picture in edited question.

Comment: You have only defined a default value, so `foo` always has a value. You should use an expression in the `@Value`. So that might be the issue, or you might have discovered an intellij issue.

Comment: It does not matter if I use default value or expression there, inspection never warns me, that this property is unused. Anyway, thank you for hints, I will post to Intellij forum